# Is it possible to have a graph with chromatic number 3 that does not have the subgraph K3?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am asked to either give an example for explain why this graph cannot exist and I'm a bit stuck. While I can't seem to think of an example of a 3-colorable graph without the complete graph K3 as a subgraph, I also don't know how to prove that every graph that has chromatic number 3 has the subgraph K3. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can have arbitrarily large chromatic number and be $K_3$ free. See [Mycielskian construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the link

Answer (score 2):

How about the cycle graph on $5$ vertices? In fact any cycle graph $G$ on an odd number $n \ge 5$ is 3-colorable (start at one node colored black, alternate black-white-black-white... and finish with red). And the chromatic number of such a cycle graph is $3$ exactly since clearly it can't be colored with $1$ color (there are adjacent vertices) nor can it be colored with $2$ colors, since starting anywhere with say black would then need to alternate black with white and run into impossibility when trying to color the final vertex in the loop. But if the odd $n$ is greater than $3$ then $G$ does not have a subgraph $K_3.$

Comment: Thank you for your help!